# yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ-What is the meaning of ZZ

Tags: spring

We have recently upgraded from spring 4.x to spring 5.x for our API application. After upgrade we are getting date format as below,
"reportedDate": "2021-09-29T07:58:42Z"-Spring 5.x
"reportedDate": "2021-06-15T15:49:35+00:00"-Spring 4.x
Below the Input format using in our code,
this.probReportCreationDate =  DateFormatUtils.formatUTC( probReportCreationDate , "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ" );

Our expectation to get format same as spring 4.x(2021-06-15T15:49:35+00:00). Need someone help here.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `Z` stands for `Zulu`, and it tells you the time is in UTC.

Previously, UTC time was signified by the `+00:00` as you show in your example, with the number being the offset from UTC.

I don't know if there is a syntax to fix it without manually replacing the `Z` with the offset.